# Python send POST with header

Tags: python, http, post, request, http-headers

I try to build a python script who sends a POST with parameters for extracting the result.
With fiddler, I have extracted the post request who return that I want. The website uses https only.

```
POST /Services/GetFromDataBaseVersionned HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mywbsite.fr
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": 129,
"Origin": "https://www.mywbsite.fr",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Referer": "https://www.mywbsite.fr/data/mult.aspx",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
"Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
"Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
"Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=j1r1b2a2v2w245; GSFV=FirstVisit=; GSRef=https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHgQFjAA&url=https://www.mywbsite.fr/&ei=FZq_T4abNcak0QWZ0vnWCg&usg=AFQjCNHq90dwj5RiEfr1Pw; HelpRotatorCookie=HelpLayerWasSeen=0; NSC_GSPOUGS!TTM=ffffffff09f4f58455e445a4a423660; GS=Site=frfr; __utma=1.219229010.1337956889.1337956889.1337958824.2; __utmb=1.1.10.1337958824; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1337956889.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)"

{"isLeftColumn":false,"lID":-1,"userIpCountryCode":"FR","version":null,"languageCode":"fr","siteCode":"frfr","Quotation":"eu"}
```

And now my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import string
import httplib
import urllib2

host = "www.mywbsite.fr/sport/multiplex.aspx"
    params='"isLeftColumn":"false","liveID":"-1","userIpCountryCode":"FR","version":"null","languageCode":"fr","siteCode":"frfr","Quotation":"eu"'

headers = { Host: www.mywbsite.fr,
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": 129,
"Origin": "https://www.mywbsite.fr",
"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
"Accept": "*/*",
"Referer": "https://www.mywbsite.fr/data/mult.aspx",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
"Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
"Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
"Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=j1r1b2a2v2w245; GSFV=FirstVisit=;     GSRef=https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHgQFjAA&url=https://www.mywbsite.fr/&ei=FZq_T4abNcak0QWZ0vnWCg&usg=AFQjCNHq90dwj5RiEfr1Pw; HelpRotatorCookie=HelpLayerWasSeen=0; NSC_GSPOUGS!TTM=ffffffff09f4f58455e445a4a423660; GS=Site=frfr; __utma=1.219229010.1337956889.1337956889.1337958824.2; __utmb=1.1.10.1337958824; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1337956889.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)"

}

url = "/Services/GetFromDataBaseVersionned"

# POST the request
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host,port=443)
conn.request("POST",url,params,headers)
response = conn.getresponse()

data = response.read()
print data
```

But when I run my script, I have this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: There is no good reason to speak HTTP manually. Use urllib or even better, [**requests**](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

Comment: Refer this answer for better explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51124572/7384392

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your link to the requests module. It's just perfect. Below the solution to my problem.

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.mywbsite.fr/Services/GetFromDataBaseVersionned'
payload = {
    "Host": "www.mywbsite.fr",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": 129,
    "Origin": "https://www.mywbsite.fr",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Referer": "https://www.mywbsite.fr/data/mult.aspx",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
    "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "Cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=j1r1b2a2v2w245; GSFV=FirstVisit=; GSRef=https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHgQFjAA&url=https://www.mywbsite.fr/&ei=FZq_T4abNcak0QWZ0vnWCg&usg=AFQjCNHq90dwj5RiEfr1Pw; HelpRotatorCookie=HelpLayerWasSeen=0; NSC_GSPOUGS!TTM=ffffffff09f4f58455e445a4a423660; GS=Site=frfr; __utma=1.219229010.1337956889.1337956889.1337958824.2; __utmb=1.1.10.1337958824; __utmc=1; __utmz=1.1337956889.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)"
}
# Adding empty header as parameters are being sent in payload
headers = {}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Why are you sending the header as the data of the request and why that works?

Comment: FYI you should *NOT* manually send headers like this. It's request's job. The maximum you should have to send is the user agent and custom headers.

Comment: what does json.dumps do?

Comment: can we send headers using `post` in `requests` `python` ?

Comment: Yes, of course, @Rohit-Pandey. You can look above or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54493776/4217744

Comment: You don't need `json.dumps`

Comment: @Engin Yapici Usually we Don't need to dump our data as json but in some special case we need it. Such as sending post request in FASTAPI, It's requires to dump our data as json.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho - agreed.  I was trying to pass a payload without `json.dumps()` and it failed, got very frustrated.  Found this answer, used `json.dumps()` and the API works like a charm.

Comment: @AntoineBolvy Interesting information. Can you provide more detail or a specific resource to read about that? I can't find any. Thankful in advance.

Comment: @py_ios_dev It converts Python objects into JSON format data.

Answer (score 129):

If we want to add **custom HTTP headers** to a **POST request**, we must pass them through **a dictionary to the** `headers` **parameter**.

Here is an example with **a non-empty *body*** and ***headers***:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://somedomain.com'
body = {'name': 'Maryja'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

[Source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python)

Comment: This reply is correct, worked for me using body to post specific keys that are supported by the server

Answer (score 5):

To make POST request instead of GET request using `urllib2`, you need to specify empty data, for example:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request("http://am.domain.com:8080/openam/json/realms/root/authenticate?authIndexType=Module&authIndexValue=LDAP")
req.add_header('X-OpenAM-Username', 'demo')
req.add_data('')
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```