# How can I get this POST request to execute in Python using Google Colab. I am currently getting a 400 response code

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to extract information for all the jobs on this website:
https://www.americanmobile.com/travel-nursing-jobs/search/

Looking at the network activity tab, it looks like all the data I need comes from a POST request made here:
https://jobs.amnhealthcare.com/api/jobs//search. I have attached an image that may help confirm exactly what I am referencing.
[example_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXJJx.png)

I wrote the following code in Google Colab to try to at least get the first 10 results. Referencing [python requests POST with header and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124516/python-requests-post-with-header-and-parameters), I know a lot of the headers may not even be necessary. I have tried sending this request without any headers at all.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I have only gotten a 400 response code so far.

If it is possible to accomplish this, is it possible to extract this information for all 4k + jobs?

```
import requests
import re
payload = {
  "PageNumber": "1",
    "JobsPerPage": "10",
    "Filters": {
        "Locations": "[]",
        "Skillset": "[]",
        "StartDates": "[]",
        "Shifts": "[]",
        "Durations": "[]",
        "IsCovid19Job": "false",
        "Exclusive": "false",
        "Skillsets": "[]",
        "DivisionCompanyId": "2",
        "LocationSearch": "",
        "KeywordSearch": "",
        "DaxtraJobIds": "[]"
    },
    "SortOrder": {
        "Header": "MaxPayRate",
        "SortDirection": "Descending"
    }
}

headers = {
    "Host": "jobs.amnhealthcare.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "315",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Origin": "https://www.americanmobile.com",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://www.americanmobile.com/",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}
response = requests.post('https://jobs.amnhealthcare.com/api/jobs//search' , data=p , headers=headers)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting of your `data` wasn't entirely correct. This should work:

```
import requests

headers = {
    "Host": "jobs.amnhealthcare.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "315",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "Origin": "https://www.americanmobile.com",
    "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
    "Referer": "https://www.americanmobile.com/",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}

data = '{"PageNumber":1,"JobsPerPage":10,"Filters":{"Locations":[],"Skillset":[],"StartDates":[],"Shifts":[],"Durations":[],"IsCovid19Job":false,"Exclusive":false,"Skillsets":[],"DivisionCompanyId":2,"LocationSearch":"","KeywordSearch":"","DaxtraJobIds":[]},"SortOrder":{"Header":"MaxPayRate","SortDirection":"Descending"}}'

response = requests.post('https://jobs.amnhealthcare.com/api/jobs//search', headers=headers, data=data)
```

You can now adapt `JobsPerPage` and `PageNumber` to retrieve all the posts you need in a for-loop.

Comment: Can confirm this works. Add `response.json()` to get the data. Looks like in RJ's answer the data payload must be sent as a string which makes sense in order for the consuming endpoint to get json to parse -- or so is my guess.