# Is it possible to run a Google App Script from Google Colab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-colaboratory

I have a Google Colab Workbook that does some scrapping and saves the scrapped files in my Google Drive and I also have a Google App Script that manipulates these files in Google Spreadsheet.

Is there a way to trigger this Google App Script directly from Google Colab? So at the end of my scrapping it does all the things I need it to do, without the need to open Google Apps Script.

I know I could write code in Google Colab that does exactly what the Google App Script does. But I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Try it.  See what happens.

Comment: I would like to try it, do not know how. Hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

You might use Google Apps Script to create a [web-app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) or you might use the [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts) then call them from Google Colaboratory by doing a HTTP request. The method to be called to execute a Google Apps Script function is [script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run).

Related

- [python requests POST with header and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51124516/1595451)
- [How to make a Post request to an API using Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71605090/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#python

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since there is a bounty for it, would you please provide a simple example?

Comment: You are welcome. Please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python (already included in the answer).

Comment: I did. And as I understand the example show how to "create a new script project, upload a file to the
project, and log the script's URL", but what I need is a way to run the script. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks that are referring to another page, not to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/python. Try closing all the other tabs in your web browser and open the link in this comment again.

Comment: I have opened the link in anonymous mode and it goes to the same page. I have found this https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md where it seams it shows how to run a script. But I am not sure. Could you provide an example in your answer?

Comment: I don't know what is happing on your side. Try using another web-browser or even a different device... or just be patient

Comment: Try this other one https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#python