# Convert PHP API call to Python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I have an existing API that I connect to using PHP and send an image, the code looks like this...

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api';
$ch = \curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Subscription-Key: 345sdf4'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{
            \"fileurl\":\"" . $this->_config['server_config']['server_url'] . $my_image . "\"
        }");
```

I am trying to convert this to Python3, I understand I need `requests` so have this so far...

```
import requests

api_url_base = 'https://example.com/api'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Subscription-Key': '345sdf4'}
```

But this is as far as I have got, how do I add the image? I know the absolute path of the image already

Comment: Your `POST` body would be something like `json.dumps(dict({'fileurl': myUrl}))`

Answer (score 2):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768522/python-send-post-with-header) you can do the following:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://example.com/api'
body = {'name': 'something'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
```

[source](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python)