# Can I return a String along with Dict in python?

Tags: python

Following is my code snippet. How can I modify my getUrlAndHeader(), so that my requests.post works. Right now I get 404 response if I use getUrlAndHeader() . Can someone please help?

```
import requests
def getUrlAndHeader():
    return "https://someurl.com, headers={'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #200#response = requests.post("https://someurl.com", headers={'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, json=[])
    #404#response = requests.post(getUrlAndHeader(), json=[])
    #print response
```

Comment: Why don't you just return a `Dict` containing a `Dict` or an Array with a `String` and a `Dict`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to return a single string. You could return a tuple, like

```
def getUrlAndHeader():
    return "https://someurl.com", {'headers': {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}}
```

but you won't be able to pass the return value directly to the argument list of `post`. (There's nothing you can unpack as a mix of positional and keyword arguments.) Instead, do something like

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url, other = getUrlAndHeader()
    response = requests.post(url, json=[], **other)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking how to make post API call then please refer this [Python send POST with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768522/python-send-post-with-header)

For your problem you can also solve this way.

```
import requests
import json


def get_url_and_headers():
    return {"url": "https://someurl.com", "headers": "{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = get_url_and_headers()
    my_payload = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
    response = requests.post(res['url'], data=json.dumps(my_payload), headers=res['headers'])
    print(response.content)
```