# Convert C# requests to Python requests

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x

I have the following code in C#:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\r\n \"content\": \"" + message + "\"\r\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I want to convert that code to python. This is what I've got so far:

```
data = {
    'content': 'test'
}


r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

I don't understand where the `application/json` part fits in.

Comment: Does this anwer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python

Comment: Nope I'm not trying to send a file

Comment: Dose this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768522/python-send-post-with-header

Answer (score 0):

`application/json` is the content-type. You can specify the content-type of your request like this

```
headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }

data = {
    'content': 'test'
}


r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```